# JQuery AJAX .load() does not work in IE, HTTP 200

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I am working on a website that uses some AJAX to load three parts of content, the content of 2 menus and a content div. It does work perfectly everywhere, but not on IE 10 (and every IE ever i suppose).

The code that loads the divs:

```
function loadUp(site){
  $("#content").load(site + ".html #content > *");
  $("#menubar").load(site + ".html #menubar > *");
  $("#secmenu").load(site + ".html #secmenu > *");
}
```

I did already google a lot, and the usual errors do not apply: I defined the charset

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

I disabled caching, which changed the HTTP answer code from 304 to 200

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup ({cache: false});
});
```

But i still can't figure out how to fix the problem. The website is online here: http://matthiasfrueh.de/

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but the request urls are wrong. Try looking at webserver logs or developer console and see how the request are formated.

Comment: The GET request points at URLs such as [http://matthiasfrueh.de/kontakt.html?_=1385140798502](http://matthiasfrueh.de/kontakt.html?_=1385140798502). I suppose that the `?_...` postfix is written by the `cache: false` option

Comment: you'd have better to use $.ajax() and do only one request

Comment: @Babblo What do you think is wrong with the URLs?

Comment: Im guessing `site` is a base URL, then you concatenate with the ".html" plus what I think are some jquery selectors.

Comment: BTW, are you sure this is valid: `#content > *`  shouldn't it be just  `#content`

Comment: @A.Wolff Would that actually solve the problem or just speed it up? I know.. Im an AJAX noob

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes it is valid, actually got that out of another stackoverflow question. Edit: Written that way, .load() only reads the content of the targeted div, not the <div> tag itself